# jquery for restricting words to be displayed

Tags: jquery-ui

im trying to restrict 120 characters to be displayed.while the rest should be represented as "(more..)".which is make clickable to view the entire content.when i enter desc with space..the "(more..)" moves to the second..if i dont use space...it moves to the first line.

```
<h:outputScript>interaction360();
function interaction360(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var maxLength = 120;
        $(".show-read-more").each(function(){
            var myStr = $(this).text();
            if($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength){
                var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
                var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
                $(this).empty().html(newStr);
                $(this).append('<span class="more-text"> (more...) </span>');
            }
        });
        $(".more-text").css("color","blue");

    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Live Demo Link : [CodePen](http://codepen.io/maxds/pen/jgeoA/)**

HTML code :

```
 <span class="more">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</span>
```

CSS Code :

```
.morecontent span { display: none; }
.morelink { display: block; }
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Configure/customize these variables.
var showChar = 120;  // How many characters are shown by default
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "Show more ...";
var lesstext = "Show less";


  $('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if(content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Hope it will work for you.